# Swift: How to show date for tomorrow

Tags: swift, date, calendar

so I'm trying to show next day from the displayed date using this code:

```
@IBAction func Future(_ sender: Any) {

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: formattedDate)!
    let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: myDate)
    let somedateString = dateFormatter.string(from: tomorrow!)




    dateText.text = somedateString
```

It works fine ,but it shows the next day from current date once. I want to make sure that if I press the button one more time it will show the day after the current date and so on. Ex if the current date is 05.02.2019 if I press the button once it should show 06.02.2019 If I press it one more time it should show 07.02.2019 and so on. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your date value with the tomorrow value every time the button is tapped:

```
var date = Date()

@IBAction func Future(_ sender: Any) {
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
   let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
   let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: formattedDate)!
   let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: myDate)
   //here
   date = tomorrow
   let somedateString = dateFormatter.string(from: tomorrow!)
    dateText.text = somedateString
 }
```